# Connection error for linux webcam driver for matlab

Tags: arch-linux, drivers, configuration, camera, matlab

This might seem like a duplicate post, well yes it is, but I have a different problem compared with the duplicate version of it.

My value for `imaqhwinfo` gives me:

```
   InstalledAdaptors: {'dcam'  'linuxvideo'}
    MATLABVersion: '7.14 (R2012a)'
      ToolboxName: 'Image Acquisition Toolbox'
   ToolboxVersion: '4.3 (R2012a)'
```

The value for `imaqhwinfo('linuxvideo',1)` gives me:

```
DefaultFormat: 'YUYV_640x480'
   DeviceFileSupported: 0
            DeviceName: '1.3M WebCam'
              DeviceID: 1
 VideoInputConstructor: 'videoinput('linuxvideo', 1)'
VideoDeviceConstructor: 'imaq.VideoDevice('linuxvideo', 1)'
      SupportedFormats: {1x7 cell}
```

So, after that I gave the following to the Matlab terminal:

```
vid = videoinput('linuxvideo', 1);
set(vid, 'ReturnedColorSpace', 'RGB');
```

However, after inputting the following line:

```
img = getsnapshot(vid);
```

I get the following error:

```
Warning: Unable to set the selected source.  Perhaps the device is in use. 
Error using imaqdevice/getsnapshot (line 62)
Could not connect to the image acquisition device.  Device may be in use.
```

I posted this question to Matlab central and am waiting for a reply.

I'm using ArchLinux(64 bit) & Matlab(2012a) ( 64 bit). Webcam apps such as Cheese are running okay. I can see my face. I also have Skype, though I haven't configured it yet.

#### TL;DR

Can anybody help me fix this issue? It would be a great help, because if I cannot, I'll have to re-install Windows 7 for just a little bit of a school assignment, and that's time consuming. Plus I don't want to go back to Windows right now.

P.S: `lsusb` gives me:

```
Bus 002 Device 005: ID 148e:099a EVATRONIX SA 
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0020 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 064e:a219 Suyin Corp. 1.3M WebCam (notebook emachines E730, Acer sub-brand)
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0020 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Comment: So are you sure that there isn't any application using the webcam? Logout and back again just to make sure.

Comment: Doesn't work mate , even after rebooting the same error message shows up .

Answer (score 1):

How about if you include the image size argument?

```
vid = videoinput(‘linuxvideo’, 1, ‘YUYV_640x480′);
```

Then try opening a preview window to view video at runtime:

```
preview(vid);
```

#### Formats

Also you can find out the acceptable formats:

```
info = imaqhwinfo('linuxvideo', 1);
info.SupportedFormats'
```

These formats can be used thusly:

```
vid = videoinput(‘linuxvideo’, 1, ‘...formats here...′);
```

#### Additional things to try?

I'd take a look at this ArchLinux forums thread titled: [[SOLVED] matlab image capturing using webcam](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=117789). There were several other things to try if the above doesn't work out.

Comment: I see an window 640x480 , but no image , however an error message again after preview(vid): `Warning: Unable to set the selected source.  Perhaps the device is in use. 
Error using imaqdevice/preview (line 177)
Could not connect to the image acquisition device.  Device may be in use.`

Comment: I think this is where Arch really caught me off-guard  , because I am in charge of making my own OS .

Comment: @MotiurRahman - yes I've tried to get to using it but it felt like a step back to me. I usually use (Fedora, Ubuntu, or Debian). For ease of use I'd use either (Mint or PCLinuxOS).

Comment: I saw you latest edit , I think I no what you are trying to do , I have done it ,but , umm , same error every time . Its a pity that I have to change an OS for an assignment , but this has been my life for the last 3-4 years , never stuck with a single OS for long enough to rot .

Comment: Yes , I saw that post on Arch , apparently , he bought a new webcam because its not supported . By my webcam is running fine , I can see video on that , its just I can't connect it with Matlab.Well , thanks for your reply , I am looking into the docs .

Comment: @motiur - Any solution to this? I have the same problem. Can see video fine on VLC. Matlab gives "could not connect to the image acquisition device. device may be in use".

Comment: @sanjay I couldn't, I used windows for Matlab,sorry.